# How to cache a page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Previously in `Windows Phone 8.0` apps, we could navigate deeper to the same page this way:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Page was cached automatically, so after navigating back, user was on the same position on the list when he left.

But in `Windows Phone Store Apps` we navigate deeper to the same page this way:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SamePage), id);
```

But after navigating back it loads data again so if user was on the middle of a long list, now he is on the top:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Create an appropriate data model for your problem domain to replace the sample data.
    var group = await SampleDataSource.GetGroupAsync((string)e.NavigationParameter);
    this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = group;
}
```

**How can I cache a page like the way it was done previously so user will be on the same position on a list where he left?**

(I included Windows apps too cause they are familiar with it from a longer time).

Comment: You should have a look at this question (you may have problems when setting cache mode to required): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539755/winrt-frame-how-to-create-new-page-instance-on-navigate-and-keep-the-page-ins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your page constructor you'll have to specify

```
    public MainPage()
    {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In App.cs you can set RootFrame.CacheSize which hints the OS how many pages it should try to keep in cache. 
Also you probably shouldn't reset the datacontext in NavigationHelper_LoadState - this method is called each time you navigate to the page, even if you navigate back.