# Navigation between pages in WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to migrate my app from WP8 to WP8.1. And I don't get how to navigate to already opened page with another parameters.

For example, I'm showing user info on UserPage giving it user's id as parameter. And when page is already is the content of the Frame I want to open UserPage again but for other user giving it another id.

My problem is that, using NavigationCacheMode set to Required for UserPage means that there will be no navigation with other parameters. But when NavigationCacheMode is set to Disabled navigation with another parameter is success but when I press back button old instance of UserPage is using data from new one.

In WP8 passing new parameters was enough to create new instance of a page with it's own cache. How to do similar in WP8.1 using WRT APIs?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539755/winrt-frame-how-to-create-new-page-instance-on-navigate-and-keep-the-page-ins

Comment: Looks like good work around this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem I'm facing is that the page transition animations do not work with these new classes

Comment: Still trying to find a solution

Comment: Maybe instead of creating instances of the same Page, you could use other solutions: define a `User Control` and the add/remove/make visible to Grid or remember the *Set of data* and switch data not Page.

Comment: Currently using this method. Works well so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Romansz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681948/romasz) for the tip about using UserControl. Using UserControl binding to a ContentControl and handling BackKeyPress solves my problem with navigation.