# Uwp application navigation between pages

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomeClass), file);
this.Frame.GoBack();
```

Hello guys,

Goback() method is creating a new instance, but i do not want it.I want the previous page stay how i left, and keeps data. Any idea about that issue?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539755/winrt-uwp-frame-and-page-caching-how-to-create-new-page-instance-on-navigate

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the NavigationCacheMode property:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs you should be setting the size of the frame's page cache. Add the line that sets the CacheSize after the NavigationFailed handler is assigned.

```
rootFrame = new Frame();

rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

// Add this line after the above 2 lines that already exist.
rootFrame.CacheSize = 2; // Or some other number that makes sense for your application
```

On the page where you want to retain data, in the XAML set the cache mode to required.

```
<Page ... NavigationCacheMode="Required" >...</Page>
```

In your codebehind, you may need to override OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo to save and restore state.

If you do not want to retain data, set NavigationCacheMode="Disabled" on that page. You still navigate using Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage));

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where i need to write rootFrame code in app.xaml.cs

Comment: And what i need to do for creating new instances of next page everytime when navigating to it and clearing all data inside ?

Comment: @alidrsn Updated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can serialize all your data of your viewmodel or class and restore or save the data to recover the previous information.

here is an example.

http://irisclasson.com/2012/07/09/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/