# How to goback the previous state of a this page

Tags: c#, uwp

I have application UWP

[image]

Left screen is SplitView.Pane with list content.

Right screen is SplitView.Content, contain detail of content.

```
<SplitView.Content>
    <Frame x:Name="frMainFrame">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
     </Frame>
</SplitView.Content>
```

When im clicked into title on the SplitView.pane, frMainFrame will navigate into ListThread page with parameter is "id"

```
frMainFrame.Navigate(typeof(ListThread), id);
```

Method handled Back button

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (frMainFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        frMainFrame.GoBack(new SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
    }
    else
    {
        DialogResult.AskToExitApp();
    }
}
```

On ListThread page,

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        idBox = (int)e.Parameter;
        Idpage = 1;
        AnalyzeUrlBox();
        AnalyzeHtml();
    }
}
```

and set NavigatitonCacheMode is Required on Constructor method:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
```

Now,

1. I'm click on Modding and wait for content load complete.(frMainFrame will navigate in to ListThread with Parameter Id = 2)
2. I'm click on AMD and wait for content load complete.(frMainFrame will navigate in to ListThread with Parameter Id = 3)
3. I'm click on Back button on the top corner left.

   - Require: frMainFrame navigate display ListThread with Parameter Id = 2, restore all state before navigate
   - Actual: frMainFrame stuck on ListThread with Parameter Id = 3

I think, the problem lies in NavigationCacheMode. How to what to execute same as Require?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to set `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` ?

Comment: I have try and seems as problem was not resolve.

I think that the problem at each page only only 1 instance cache.

If me navigation from ListThread to page Thread.Xaml, click backbutton, the ListThread is Restore the complete.

Comment: `Frame.GoBack()` Navigates to the most recent item in back navigation history such as ([Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page)) , So I think you should try to create `new` Instances for each item (AMD,Modding , ...) and navigate to it to preserve history and keep loaded data.

Comment: I tried with search with your help and succeeded.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539755/winrt-uwp-frame-and-page-caching-how-to-create-new-page-instance-on-navigate

Thanks!